# Download files from AmazonS3 bucket using curl

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, curl, download, travis-ci

During the build on Travis CI, how can I download files from AmazonS3 bucket using curl with Access Key and Secret Key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Travis CI, but the only way to download private content via a URL would be to generate an [Amazon S3 pre-signed URLs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html), which is a time-limited URL (so it changes each time).

The preferred method would be to download using the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/), which manages the security via credentials stored in a configuration file.